# Apt install not working for tensorflow installation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build tensorflow from source. I just typed the step 1 from the [website][1] and this is what I got. Can anyone help me with this error?

````
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip

Ign:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libpython3.8-dev arm64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libpython3-dev arm64 3.8.2-0ubuntu2
  Connection failed[IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe arm64 python-pip-whl all 20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6
  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 python3.8-dev arm64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4
Err:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 python3-dev arm64 3.8.2-0ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
Err:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 python3-setuptools all 45.2.0-1
  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
Err:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe arm64 python3-wheel all 0.34.2-1
  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
Err:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe arm64 python3-pip all 20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6
  Connection failed[IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libpython3.8-dev arm64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4
  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 python3.8-dev arm64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4
  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python3.8/libpython3.8-dev_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4_arm64.deb  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/libpython3-dev_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python-pip-whl_20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6_all.deb  Connection failed[IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python3.8/python3.8-dev_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4_arm64.deb  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-dev_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Connection failed[IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/setuptools/python3-setuptools_45.2.0-1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/w/wheel/python3-wheel_0.34.2-1_all.deb  Connection failed[IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python3-pip_20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?```


  [1]: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source
````

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a network related issue of the ubuntu package manager apt. It might be on topic for https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: `Connection failed [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 80]` <- seems to an issue that `apt` is unable to reach the required web resources. Has nothing to do with python or tensorflow specifically